# How to avoid boiler plate code when calling getters and setters?

Tags: c++

I wonder if there is a way to avoid boiler plate code like this in C++.

```
    /* Set PWM */
    cSVeasurement.setPwm0(slopeAndBias(PWM[0], 0, 65535, iOcalibration->getPwm0Min(), iOcalibration->getPwm0Max()));
    cSVeasurement.setPwm1(slopeAndBias(PWM[1], 0, 65535, iOcalibration->getPwm1Min(), iOcalibration->getPwm1Max()));
    cSVeasurement.setPwm2(slopeAndBias(PWM[2], 0, 65535, iOcalibration->getPwm2Min(), iOcalibration->getPwm2Max()));
    cSVeasurement.setPwm3(slopeAndBias(PWM[3], 0, 65535, iOcalibration->getPwm3Min(), iOcalibration->getPwm3Max()));
    cSVeasurement.setPwm4(slopeAndBias(PWM[4], 0, 65535, iOcalibration->getPwm4Min(), iOcalibration->getPwm4Max()));
    cSVeasurement.setPwm5(slopeAndBias(PWM[5], 0, 65535, iOcalibration->getPwm5Min(), iOcalibration->getPwm5Max()));
    cSVeasurement.setPwm6(slopeAndBias(PWM[6], 0, 65535, iOcalibration->getPwm6Min(), iOcalibration->getPwm6Max()));
    cSVeasurement.setPwm7(slopeAndBias(PWM[7], 0, 65535, iOcalibration->getPwm7Min(), iOcalibration->getPwm7Max()));
```

Instead, I want to have something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    cSVeasurement.setPwm##i##(slopeAndBias(PWM[i], 0, 65535, iOcalibration->getPwm##i##Min(), iOcalibration->getPwm##i##Max()));
```

Is that possible? I know that I could use a macro by using `##` as parameter, but it will still become large boiler plate code.

Comment: What type is `cSVeasurement`? What type is `iOcalibration`? That doesn't look like any Qt class.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik These are two objects only that holds getters and setters.

Comment: This just looks like a generic C++ question, rather than a Qt question. Maybe make a single `setPwm()` function, but pass in the index as a parameter?

Comment: Yeah, the answer is "don't have eight related functions whose names differ only by a numeral". How to implement that in your use case is outside the scope of the information we've been given.

Comment: Judging by implicated functionality, you rather need a visitor which woul do interpolation instead of using getters\setters directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider having a getter that gets the min/max range then have the function take that range. If nothing else, just use a `std::pair` for the range. Then index instead of having index-named functions. Then you are left with…

```
for (auto i = 0; i != 8; ++i) {
    cSVeasurement.setPwm(i, slopeAndBias(
        PWM[i], 
        {0, 65’535}, 
        iOcalibration->getPwmMinMax(i));
}
```

and if you want it tighter still, then put that in a function:

```
// If pre-C++20, you can’t use auto for argument types:
void getSlopeAndBias(std::size_t i, const auto& PWM, const auto& cal) {
    return slopeAndBias(
        PWM[i], 
        {0, 65’535}, 
        cal.getPwmMinMax(i));
}

void setPwmSlopeAndBias(auto& dest, std::size_t i, const auto& PWM, const auto& cal) {
    dest.setPwm(i, getSlopeAndBias(i, PWM, cal));
}

…

for (auto i = 0; i != 8; ++i) {
    setPwmSlopeAndBias(cSVeasurement, i, PWM, *iOcalibration);
}
```